# Query only basic UserInfo from Azure AD with limited permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to build a list of emailadresses of all employees in our company.
This is in a Web App running on Azure, with Azure AD authentication. The app uses .NET Framework 4.6, and uses the `Microsoft.Owin.Security` packages to connect to Azure AD.

I can authenticate, I am authorized by my role as defined in the app registration. So far so good.
I can check out my own User Profile. This uses the `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient` package to build the queries, instead of manually creating the HTTPRequests.

```
string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current
    .FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,
    async () => await authorizationHelper.GetTokenForApplication());

var result = await activeDirectoryClient.Users
    .Where(u => u.ObjectId.Equals(userObjectID))
    .ExecuteAsync();

IUser user = result.CurrentPage.ToList().First();
```

AD computes my query, sees that it only returns me, and deduces that I am allowed to view my own info. Execute succeeds, returning just me.

On a different page, I want to show the mail addresses used in the company (to tag a user, to typeahead, to check for existance, etc.) I try the following:

```
result = await activeDirectoryClient.Users
    .ExecuteAsync();
return result.CurrentPage
    .ToList();
```

This fails, "insufficient privileges". I am not allowed to view the entire User I guess. My delegated permissions are to "Read all users' basic profiles", [meaning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes):

> Allows the app to read the basic profile of all users in the
>   organization on behalf of the signed-in user. The following properties
>   comprise a user’s basic profile: display name, first and last name,
>   photo, and email address.

So, I try to filter:

```
result = await activeDirectoryClient.Users
    .Where(u => u.Mail.StartsWith(str))
    .ExecuteAsync();
return result.CurrentPage
    .ToList();
```

but that still gives me the entire User, and I'm yet again hit with "insufficient privileges". So I try

```
result = await activeDirectoryClient.Users
    .Where(u => u.Mail.StartsWith(str))
    .Select (u => u.Mail)
    .ExecuteAsync();
return result.CurrentPage
    .ToList();
```

Which gives the cryptic runtime error (free translation from Dutch)

```
GenericArguments[1], System.String, Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions
.ReadOnlyQueryableSet.`2[TSource,TISource] conflicts with type TISource.
```

And I am at a loss. No source code seems to be available for `ActiveDirectoryClient`, and the usual Graph API [doesn't even mention selecting only basic info.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#CommonQueries)

The "easy" solution would be "just get more app permissions", but that needs a lot of time to go through the bureaucracy. And I *SHOULD* be able to get all Users' mail, right?

Comment: Could you please show the `GetTokenForApplication` function ? Please try to decode the access token using [online tool](https://jwt.io/) and check  the permissions in `scp`claim .

Comment: Very useful, I could now compare the tokens I got from my local working version and the webapp version. I was missing permissions, the box was checked but the permissions never *granted*. Sigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, you don't need to do anything special to "Query only basic UserInfo from Azure AD with limited permissions". You just query Users, and it will initialize any fields you do not have access to as `null`. `Insufficient privileges` means you're not allowed to look at the user at all. Red flag.

At first I thought my tokencache was faulty. Which it was. Then I fixed it. Still errors.

By looking at several tokens in different applications with the [online tool](https://jwt.io/) linked by Nan Yu I found out I was missing the actual permission to look at users' basic profiles in my token.
I still didn't get the permission in the token, and found out that even though the checkbox under "Delegated Permissions" was checked, the "Grant Permissions" option was not succesfully used afterwards.

PSA: don't assume all checked boxes are actually granted. Check in the App Service which permissions it has. If you're allowed that by your company, that is.